# Python RuntimeWarning overflow encountered in double_scalars

Tags: python, c, numpy, overflow, warnings

I'm trying to port a "C" code to Python, this is what I coded:

```
scale = 1.0 / (rows * cols)
RemoveConstantBiasFrom(rarray, scale)
zarray = rarray[:]
zarray = DCT(zarray, rows, cols)

zarray = zarray.flatten()

beta = np.dot(rarray, zarray)

if iloop == 0:
    parray = zarray[:]
else:
    btemp = beta / beta_prev
    parray = zarray + btemp * parray
RemoveConstantBiasFrom(parray, scale)
beta_prev = beta
for j in range(rows):
        for i in range(cols):
            k = j * rows + i

            k1 = k + 1 if i < cols - 1 else k - 1
            k2 = k - 1 if i > 0 else k + 1
            k3 = k + cols if j < rows - 1 else k - cols
            k4 = k - cols if j > 0 else k + cols


            w1 = SIMIN(wts[k], wts[k1])
            w2 = SIMIN(wts[k], wts[k2])
            w3 = SIMIN(wts[k], wts[k3])
            w4 = SIMIN(wts[k], wts[k4])

            A = (w1 + w2 + w3 + w4) * parray[k]
            B = (w1 * parray[k1] + w2 * parray[k2])
            C = (w3 * parray[k3] + w4 * parray[k4])

            zarray[k] = A - (B + C)
```

`wts` and `parray` are two flattened arrays with 262144 values (a 512x512 matrix). When I'm perfoming this operation I get:

```
test.py:152: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  B = (w1 * parray[k1] + w2 * parray[k2])
test.py:154: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  C = (w3 * parray[k3] + w4 * parray[k4])
test.py:155: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  zarray[k] = A - B + C
```

So, I started to "debug" the code.

1) I put a `print` to `max(parray)` before the loops and I obtained:

```
Maximum value for parray  15.2665322926
```

2) I added an if statement inside the loop to watch `parray[k1]` behavior `if parray[k1] > maxparray: print k1` and I obtained a lot of "k1's":

```
...
251902
252414
252926
253438
253950
254462
254974
255486
255998
256510
257022
257534
258046
258558
259070
259582
260094
260606
261118
261630
262142
```

So, the question: If I never changed "parray" why I'm getting different values exceeding `max(parray)`?

This is the C code:

```
  int     i, j, k;
  int     k1, k2, k3, k4;
  double  sum, w1, w2, w3, w4, btemp, delta, avg, scale;
  float   *wts;

  scale = 1.0/(xsize*ysize);
  /* remove constant bias from rarray */
  for (k=0, avg=0.0; k<xsize*ysize; k++)  avg += rarray[k];
  avg *= scale;
  for (k=0; k<xsize*ysize; k++)  rarray[k] -= avg;
  /* compute cosine transform solution of Laplacian in rarray */
  for (k=0; k<xsize*ysize; k++)  {
    zarray[k] = rarray[k];
  }
  DCT(zarray, xsize, ysize, xcos, ycos);
  /* calculate beta and parray */
  for (k=0, *beta=0.0; k<xsize*ysize; k++) {
    *beta += rarray[k]*zarray[k];
  }
  printf("beta = %lf\n", *beta);
  if (iloop == 0) {
    for (k=0; k<xsize*ysize; k++) {
      parray[k] = zarray[k];
    }
  }
  else {
    btemp = (*beta)/(*beta_prev);
    for (k=0; k<xsize*ysize; k++) {
      parray[k] = zarray[k] + btemp*parray[k];
    }
  }
  /* remove constant bias from parray */
  for (k=0, avg=0.0; k<xsize*ysize; k++)  avg += parray[k];
  avg *= scale;
  for (k=0; k<xsize*ysize; k++)  parray[k] -= avg;
  *beta_prev = *beta;
  /* calculate Qp */
  for (j=0; j<ysize; j++) {
    for (i=0; i<xsize; i++) {
      k = j*xsize + i;
      k1 = (i<xsize-1) ? k + 1 : k - 1;
      k2 = (i>0) ? k - 1 : k + 1;
      k3 = (j<ysize-1) ? k + xsize : k - xsize;
      k4 = (j>0) ? k - xsize : k + xsize;
      if (dxwts==NULL && dywts==NULL) {  /* unweighted */
        w1 = w2 = w3 = w4 = 1.0;
      }
      else if (dxwts==NULL || dywts==NULL) {  /* one set of wts */
        wts = (dxwts) ? dxwts : dywts;
        w1 = SIMIN(wts[k], wts[k1]);
        w2 = SIMIN(wts[k], wts[k2]);
        w3 = SIMIN(wts[k], wts[k3]);
        w4 = SIMIN(wts[k], wts[k4]);
      }
      else {    /* dxwts and dywts are both supplied */
        w1 = dxwts[k];
        w2 = (i>0) ? dxwts[k-1] : dxwts[k];
        w3 = dywts[k];
        w4 = (j>0) ? dywts[k-xsize] : dywts[k];
      }

      zarray[k] = (w1 + w2 + w3 + w4)*parray[k]
                        - (w1*parray[k1] + w2*parray[k2] 
                                + w3*parray[k3] + w4*parray[k4]);
    }
  }
```

*I'm just passing `dxwts` (one set of weights) so the others are not needed, that's why I'm using one if statement, where SIMIN is:*

```
#define SIMIN(x,y) (((x)*(x) < (y)*(y)) ? (x)*(x) : (y)*(y))
```

Comment: How is zarray initialised?

Comment: It is obtained by a direct cosine transform function which returns a 512x512 array, and then it is flattened and copied to parray

Comment: I suppose that rows == cols in this case, but `k = j * rows + i` is not correct; it should be `j * cols + i` if `j` is the row index (`j in range(rows)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way I'm copying the arrays, the correct way is:

```
zarray[:] = rarray
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is that `parray` and `zarray` are the same array.

If you do this:

```
zarray = DCTF()
parray = zarray
```

then `zarray` and `parray` are *the same array* and changing an element in `zarray` will be visible in uses of `parray`. (This is not significantly different from C.)

If you want a copy, you can do this:

```
zarray = DCTF()
parray = zarray[:]
```

Comment: I have the following code: `    scale = 1.0 / (rows * cols)
    RemoveConstantBiasFrom(rarray, scale)
    zarray = rarray[:]
    zarray = DCT(zarray, rows, cols)
   
    zarray = zarray.flatten()

    beta = np.dot(rarray, zarray)

    if iloop == 0:
        parray = zarray[:]
    else:
        btemp = beta / beta_prev
        parray = zarray + btemp * parray
    RemoveConstantBiasFrom(parray, scale)
    beta_prev = beta`  before the loops I'm still getting the warnings

Comment: @FacundoGFlores: Do you still find that the maximum of parray is mysteriously changing? (By the way, is the code pasted in your comment changed or the actual code you were using before? Either way, it would be more readable as an edit to your question.)

Comment: I have changed the code as you advised me, and I'm still observing "k1s" such that `parray[k1] > max(parray)`. I will edit the question now.